# hibernate create generic object from a query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I need to consult data of DB without use **Entity** classes.

My query like this

```
SELECT count(e), MONTHNAME(e.someDate)  /*and maybe anothers*/
FROM Entity e
WHERE ......    
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(e.someDate) 
ORDER BY e.someDate desc
```

This simple query is a search for totals in months.

The SQL query that generate is right, this return data similar to this.

```
+-----+---------+
|count|MONTHNAME|
+-----+---------+
|15   |January  |
+-----+---------+
|31   |December |
+-----+---------+
|18   |November |
+-----+---------+
```

In java code i get the query via `list` method

```
List<Object> objs = query.list();
```

When i debug, get this in object value

[image: example]

But, i cant work with this objects, `objs.get(index)` return a `object` without any method that return my data `total` or `month`

How to build the object from the query? to work data.

Comment: Have you trie to put `e` in the `SELECT` part of the query? Like `SELECT count(e), e
FROM Entity e
WHERE ......    
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(e.someDate) 
ORDER BY e.someDate desc `

Comment: But I'm not interested objects (rows in the database), I only interested in the `total` and `month`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try typecasting `objs.get(index)` to `Object[]`.
Say the result of this is `r` (`r` is for row).
Then you should be able to access your two columns by `r[0]` and `r[1]`.

Try this.

```
List<Object> objs = query.list();

for (int i=0; i<objs.size(); i++){
    Object row = objs.get(i);
    Object[] r = (Object[])row;
    System.out.println(r[0] + " " + r[1]);
}
```

Comment: I get this Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List` to `Object[]`

Comment: @jasilva Did you typecast objs or objs.get(0) to Object[]? I meant you cast objs.get(0) to an Object[].

Comment: @jasilva Good to hear that. Good luck.